# Как сделать таймер?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таймер обратного отсчёта. Отсчитывает время до указанной даты.
Как сделать таймер, чтобы он также отсчитывал время до указанной даты, а потом отсчитывал время по заданному интервалу?

Например, есть таймер, у которого указана дата "March 29,2016 20:00".
Как только таймер досчитал до указанной даты, он начинает новый отсчёт 48 часов с указанной даты. А по прошествии 48 часов опять отсчитывает 48 часов?

И возможно ли как-то указывать дату в формате 29/03/2016 20:00?

```
function get_timer() {

    var date_new = "March 29,2016 20:00";

    var date_t = new Date(date_new);
    var date = new Date();
    var timer = date_t - date;

    if (date_t > date) {

        var day = parseInt(timer / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24));

        if (day < 10) {
            day = '0' + day;
        }

        day = day.toString();

        var hour = parseInt(timer / (60 * 60 * 1000)) % 24;

        if (hour < 10) {
            hour = '0' + hour;
        }

        hour = hour.toString();

        var min = parseInt(timer / (1000 * 60)) % 60;

        if (min < 10) {
            min = '0' + min;
        }

        min = min.toString();
        var sec = parseInt(timer / 1000) % 60;
        if (sec < 10) {
            sec = '0' + sec;
        }

        sec = sec.toString();

        if (day[1] == 9 &&
            hour[0] == 2 &&
            hour[1] == 3 &&
            min[0] == 5 &&
            min[1] == 9 &&
            sec[0] == 5 &&
            sec[1] == 9) {
            animation($(".day0"), day[0]);
        } else {
            $(".day0").html(day[0]);
        }

        if (hour[0] == 2 &&
            hour[1] == 3 &&
            min[0] == 5 &&
            min[1] == 9 &&
            sec[0] == 5 &&
            sec[1] == 9) {
            animation($(".day1"), day[1]);
        } else {
            $(".day1").html(day[1]);
        }

        if (hour[1] == 3 &&
            min[0] == 5 &&
            min[1] == 9 &&
            sec[0] == 5 &&
            sec[1] == 9) {
            animation($(".hour0"), hour[0]);
        } else {
            $(".hour0").html(hour[0]);
        }

        if (min[0] == 5 &&
            min[1] == 9 &&
            sec[0] == 5 &&
            sec[1] == 9) {
            animation($(".hour1"), hour[1]);
        } else {
            $(".hour1").html(hour[1]);
        }

        if (min[1] == 9 &&
            sec[0] == 5 &&
            sec[1] == 9) {
            animation($(".min0"), min[0]);
        } else {
            $(".min0").html(min[0]);
        }

        if (sec[0] == 5 && sec[1] == 9) {
            animation($(".min1"), min[1]);
        } else {
            $(".min1").html(min[1]);
        }

        if (sec[1] == 9) {
            animation($(".sec0"), sec[0]);
        } else {
            $(".sec0").html(sec[0]);
        }
        animation($(".sec1"), sec[1]);
        setTimeout(get_timer, 1000);
    }

}

function animation(vibor, param) {
    vibor.html(param)
        .css({
            'opacity': '0'
        })
        .animate({
            'opacity': '1'
        });
}

get_timer();
```

Comment: А как таймер должен и должен ли выводить результат: в каком формате или он должен работать в фоновом режиме?

Comment: И ещё вопрос по поводу 48 часов: вам нужно именно 48 часов или от текущей даты до указанной ... Что-то не совсем понял.

Comment: Таймер выводит отсчёт в дивах $(".min1").html(min[1]); (http://webformyself.com/tajmer-obratnogo-otscheta-dlya-sajta/). Таймер считает от текущей даты до указанной до того момента, пока текущая не стала больше указанной. После этого уже отсчитывает 48 часов, и после окончания ещё 48 часов, и т.д.